# Can I swap 2 folder names in Windows when files are in use

Tags: windows, network-shares, file-transfer

I am a user with write access to a Windows network share. Every few months I update the files on this share but often they are locked or in use, especially `exe` or `dll` files. The workaround is to rename the current file (the file name changes, but the handle remains attached to the renamed file) and then copy the new file over.

Copying files individually is tedious and risky. I would prefer to simply make an entire new folder, then swap the folder names. However I haven't yet found a workaround to get it done when files are locked as above.

Is this possible? It needs to run from the command line on the client, I don't have login access to the server.

**Edit: Added workaround to replace files below in case it makes everything clearer.**

```
C:\Users\user>copy c:\newfiles\script.cmd \\server\directory\script.cmd
Overwrite \\server\directory\script.cmd? (Yes/No/All): y
Access is denied.
        0 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\user>move \\server\directory\script.cmd \\server\directory\script.cmd.back & copy c:\newfiles\script.cmd \\server\directory\script.cmd
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) copied.
```

Comment: You cannot modify files in use on Windows.

Comment: The move command definitely works to rename the file, however that might be because the contents are not changed, just the label.